# How to return biggest x coordinate and biggest y coordinate from a list of segments?

Tags: python, list, max

So, I have a bunch of segments as inputs, that are made of x coordinates and y coordinates. Horizontal segments have left and right x coordinates, and a unique y coordinate, while vertical segments have up and down y coordinates and a unique x coordinate. 
I figured out they are gonna look like this:

Horizontal segment = ((2,8), 4)

Vertical segment = (3, (2,5))

All segments = [((2,8), 1), (3, (2,5)), (5, (3,4)), (4, (6,7))]

I want to return the biggest x coordinate and the biggest y coordinate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can solve it:

```
data = [((2,8), 1), (3, (2,5)), (5, (3,4)), (4, (6,7))]
x = []
y = []
for elem in data:
    if type(elem[0])==tuple:
        x.append(max(elem[0]))
    else:
        x.append(elem[0])
    if type(elem[1])==tuple:
        y.append(max(elem[1]))
    else:
        y.append(elem[1])

print("Max(x) =",max(x))
print("Max(y) =",max(y))
```

Output:

```
Max(x) = 8
Max(y) = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract the none-tuple values in your list then you can try something like this:

```
d = [((2,8), 1), (3, (2,5)), (5, (3,4)), (4, (6,7))]
d_x = [x for x, y in d if not isinstance(x, tuple)]
d_y = [y for x, y in d if not isinstance(y, tuple)]

print ("Max X:", max(d_x))
print ("Max Y:", max(d_y))
```

Edit:

Just wanted to see how short it could be written and came up with this one-liner:

```
max_x, max_y = map(lambda l : max([max(i) if isinstance(i, tuple) else i for i in l]), zip(*input_list))
```

Comment: I need to examine also the tuples for the biggest x coordinate.